# Divide an element of a vector between the number of consecutive 0 which precede

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
20 0 20 40 0 0 0 40 20 0 20 0 20 0 0 60
```

and I want to get the following output using R:

```
20 10 10 40 10 10 10 10 20 10 10 10 10 20 20 20
```

Comment: What happens if the last number in sequence is zero?

Comment: in my data that is never gonna happen

Comment: The question is unclear and will likely be closed unless you include additional details. Most importantly, you should explain **in the question** how you get from input to output.

Comment: As far as I understand (and reflected in my answer), every index that follows a 0 or a group of zeros gets divided in equal parts between itself and the preceeding zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this is the algorithm you are looking for:

```
# data:
# original vector
a <- c(20, 0, 20, 40, 0, 0, 0, 40, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0, 60)
# expected results
b <- c(20, 10, 10, 40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20)

ramon_algo <- function(vec) {
  # Ramon algorithm?
  # Does something special when it encounters a 0 in a vector...

  n <- length(vec)
  result <- numeric(n)
  index <- 1L
  zeros_inrow <- 0L
  while (index <= n) {
    if (vec[index] != 0) {
      result[(index - zeros_inrow):index] <- vec[index] / (zeros_inrow + 1)
      zeros_inrow <- 0L
      index <- index + 1L
    } else {
      zeros_inrow <- zeros_inrow + 1L
      index <- index + 1L
    }
  }
  result
}

# Now testing it:
ramon_algo(a)
 [1] 20 10 10 40 10 10 10 10 20 10 10 10 10 20 20 20

identical(ramon_algo(a), b)
[1] TRUE
```

This might not be fastest way but at least a start.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this can be achieved by appropriately grouping and averaging within each group. With help of `data.table` this becomes a "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a)[order(rev(seq_along(a))), b := mean(a), by = cumsum(a != 0)][, b]
```

> ```
>  [1] 20 10 10 40 10 10 10 10 20 10 10 10 10 20 20 20
> ```

#### Explanation

*Divide an element of a vector between the number of consecutive 0 which preceed* is to replace the zeros plus the subsequent non-zero number by the average of all that numbers. So the problem can be reduced to define the groups.

It's easier to identify a non-zero number followed by a sequence of zeros instead of  finding a group of zeros folloed by a non-zero number. So, if we reverse the order of `a` we get

```
rev(a)
```

> ```
>  [1] 60  0  0 20  0 20  0 20 40  0  0  0 40 20  0 20
> ```

With

```
cumsum(rev(a) != 0)
```

> ```
>  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 6 7 7 8
> ```

we get a consecutive count of every non-zero entry in the reversed vector. This can be used as a group index of a non-zero and its subsequent zeros for averaging the group. `data.table` is used because of its concise syntax to assign the group average to all rows of the group using *assignment by reference* `:=`.